# ZipFileOutputFormat not giving output in .zip format mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2, outputformat

i have an application where i read HBase and write records into files.
Final output should be in .zip compressed format not hadoop supported format .
For this i have used custom ZipFileOutputFormat  to get records in .zip files.

Here is my implementation

```
ZipFileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
```

This is details of the ZipFileOutputFormat.class

```
public class ZipFileOutputFormat extends FileOutputFormat<NullWritable, Text> {
    @Override
    public RecordWriter<NullWritable, Text> getRecordWriter(
            TaskAttemptContext job) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Path file = getDefaultWorkFile(job, ".zip");

        FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(job.getConfiguration());

        return new ZipRecordWriter(fs.create(file, false));
    }

    public static class ZipRecordWriter extends
            RecordWriter<NullWritable, Text> {
        protected ZipOutputStream zos;

        public ZipRecordWriter(FSDataOutputStream os) {
            zos = new ZipOutputStream(os);
        }

        @Override
        public void write(NullWritable key, Text value) throws IOException,
                InterruptedException {
            // TODO: create new ZipEntry & add to the ZipOutputStream (zos)
        }

        @Override
        public void close(TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException,
                InterruptedException {
            zos.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I am not getting any error but my output in still in r-000001 format .

Am i missing any configuration here ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem .
After setting below in the job conf my problem has been removed

```
LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass(job, ZipFileOutputFormat.class);
```

Before it was

```
LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass(job, TextInputFormat.class);
```

Also set

```
job.setOutputFormatClass(ZipFileOutputFormat.class);
```